# convert cell to empty nested structure

Tags: matlab, struct, cell

imagine you have a cell Array "test" with two dimensions "e" and "f" of different size. Is it possible to convert this with one dimension to a struct while the other one to the substruct? It works with a Loop, but i don't like Loops. Cause the struct is empty before i can't arrange in an Array with [...].

```
StrA.SubA.SubSubA=struct('SubSubSubA',[],'SubSubSubB',[]);
count_e=4;
count_f=2;
for e=1:count_e
    for f=1:count_f
    StrA.SubA(e,1).SubSubA(f,1).SubSubSubA=test{e,f};
    end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you don't like loops.. If it works, I don't see the point..

Comment: If you're not a fan of loops then I'd avoid doubly nested structs. Is this too slow/impractical to use or is it just a syntax preference? If it's the latter maybe just move on

Comment: Loops become slow when the length of the dimensions increase. That's the important point. But i also think a solution with a less structured database is easier to  handle. Thanks to gnovice, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without loops using [`struct`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html), [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html), and a couple of [transposes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html):

```
test = num2cell(rand(4, 2));  % Sample 4-by-2 cell array of random data
StrA = struct('SubA', struct('SubSubA', num2cell(struct('SubSubSubA', test, ...
                                                        'SubSubSubB', []).', 1)).');
```

Although I don't know if it will be any faster or more readable than the loop-based solution.

I should also note that in your loop-based solution, only substructures `StrA.SubA(1).SubSubA(1)` and `StrA.SubA(1).SubSubA(2)` will have a `SubSubSubB` field. All other substructures in `StrA.SubA(2:4)` will only contain the field `SubSubSubA`.